# How do I prompt a user for a password in HTML/JS that they cannot just find the password in the page source?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out how to make local authentication without a username, just a given password that when correctly entered it will reveal the rest of the page, and if incorrectly, it should let me run code.

How would I go about setting this up?

Comment: With a server side technology.

Comment: Encrypt everything and let them enter the decryption key. That's about all you get when doing stuff clientside.

Comment: No matter how complicated you make the encryption, the user could simply go into the debugger and bypass the check.

Comment: Not if he encrypts the file with a good algorithm and a long key (password)

Answer (score 0):

Just use AES with a long key (at least 256 bit) to encrypt the file that you want to hide and have the user enter/load the key. Also, pad the file with random content (for example in comments) so it is long enough (1MB). Then ask all the geniuses who downvoted you to try to break it.

https://code.google.com/archive/p/crypto-js/